# Is it safe to remove configuration files for older kernels?

Tags: apt, package-management, kernel, dpkg

Using `dpkg -l` shows, that there are still configuration files for older kernels (?) available:

```
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-32-generic          4.13.0-32.35~16.04.1 
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic          4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1
...
rc  linux-image-4.13.0-36-generic          4.13.0-36.40~16.04.1
...
rc  linux-modules-4.15.0-32-generic        4.15.0-32.35
...
rc  linux-modules-extra-4.15.0-29-generic  4.15.0-29.31
...
rc  linux-signed-image-4.4.0-112-generic   4.4.0-112.135
```

Is it safe to remove all those configuration files with `apt-get purge <package name>`? Or is it possible, that currently used configuration files also get deleted by that?

Comment: dont forget linux-headers-x.xx.xx.xxx and linux-headers-x.xx.xx.xxx-generic

Comment: yes, that should be fine. Actually I usually do it via dpkg, example: `sudo dpkg -P linux-headers-5.3.0-050300rc8-lowlatency`. there are some tools to help. One is [here](https://launchpad.net/linux-purge)

Comment: if you want to purge any package with status 'rc'  `sudo apt purge $(dpkg -l | egrep '^rc' | awk '{print $2}')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Short Answer**: I guess it's safe.

**Longer Answer**:
Using the information from the comments to the question, I deleted all rc packages on my system. Even after the deletion the system remained stable. Therefore I guess it's ok to say it's safe.